# Django form save related object only if form is valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I think I have a rather uncommon feature here, at least I couldn't find a answer.

What I'd like to achieve is a `text input with autocomplete` on a `related model` with its label field. the given text should then `get_or_create` the related model. this already works but the problem is, that the new related model instance is saved on form submit no matter if the form is_valid or not.

given the following situation and implementation (shortened for better overview)

```py
class Correspondent(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(_("label"), max_length=100, unique=True)


class Document(BaseModel):
    correspondent = models.ForeignKey(
        Correspondent,
        verbose_name=_("correspondent"),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="documents",
    )
```

with the following form:

```py
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    correspondent = forms.CharField(
        label=_("correspondent"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "awesomplete"})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ["created_by", "modified_by"]

    def clean_correspondent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ToDo: don't save the FKed instance if complete form isn't valid
        user = self.initial["user"]
        data = self.cleaned_data["correspondent"]
        obj = Correspondent.objects.get_or_create(label=data)
        return obj
```

so the problem here is `obj.save()` which is called before `form.is_valid()` and I couldn't figure a way yet how to solve this. I'd like to prevent the creation of a new Correspondent instance if the form isn't valid yet.

Let me know if I can improve this question and thx for any hints.

Comment: Is there a reason behind not putting this logic in `if form.is_valid():` block?

Comment: Hey Dipen. Well, there is no `form` object available inside the `clean_correspondent` method. the actual `form` is available via `self` though, but it tells me `valid=True` which is correct for just the given field I guess, but maybe not for the complete form. But thx for your input. Maybe I do it wrong?

Comment: Ideally `clean_<field>` should only do cleaning. Try to move your logic out of it. Particularly in the `if form.is_valid():` block of the view in which you are dealing with the form.

Comment: Yeah ok, the problem is that I can't clean the field without having a `Correspondent` instance. Or is there maybe a way to tell django like a star wars yedi, "no django, it is fine, you can accept it!" ? :)
Also if I just return the `obj` without `.save()` I get an Exception "value cannot be null" iirc...

Comment: Yes! Thx for putting me in the right direction! I needed to replace the fields with "dummy" CharFields and in the view I can do the logic ... works nice and feels right! ... going to answer my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to Dipen Dadhaniya for pushing me in the right direction.

I needed to exclude the *actual* field from the ModelForm so I could just clean in a more simple way as CharField needs it. Afterwards in the View I can do the logic, after the whole form is valid indeed.

the form *looses* the complete custom clean_correspondent method.

```py
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    correspondent_label = forms.CharField(
        label=_("correspondent"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "awesomplete"})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ["correspondent", "created_by", "modified_by"]
```

the logic is now in the `DocumentCreateView` in the `form_valid()` method.

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.modified_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.correspondent, created = Correspondent.objects.get_or_create(
            label=form.cleaned_data["correspondent_label"]
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Bingo! :)